# SSRS expression to get quarter and year from timestamp value using cube data

Tags: expression, ssrs-2012

I am trying to write an ssrs expression that takes a parameter value, formats it to timestamp, then from that timestamp displays the regulatory year and quarter. For example, if the parameter is 01/01/2016 then it should format the parameter to be 2016-01-01 00:00:00 and then from that display the regulatory year and quarter such as Q4 2015/2016. My data is stored in a cube that uses the timestamp to get the regulatory year and quarter.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to do this would be have all versions of the required value in a complete date dimension. This could then return the different formats required.

If that's not an option, I'd try constructing the date parts in SQL first. I just find this easier to write vs SSRS expression syntax. Even if you have to create this as a dataset within the report and pass the result in as an expression.

Eg:

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN DATEPART(M, GETDATE()) < '4' THEN CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) -1 AS VARCHAR) + '/' + SUBSTRING(CAST(DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR),3,2)
        ELSE CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) + '/' + SUBSTRING(CAST(DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE()) + 1 AS VARCHAR),3,2)
    END
```

Results the current financial year:

2016/17

Comment: Could something like this be implemented instead? =IIF(Format(Parameters!PeriodFrom.Value,"yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00") = [Scheduled Calendar].[Day Time Stamp].[Day Time Stamp],[Scheduled Calendar].[Regulatory Period].[Regulatory Quarter],0)